# If there is no wljarbuilder.jar file on a weblogic installation, how else can you generate a wlfullclient.jar file?

Tags: java, jenkins, weblogic, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to create a wlfullclient.jar file for the jenkins weblogic deployment plugin, but it appears the installation I have for weblogic doesn't include the server/lib folder, let alone the wljarbuilder.

I've done a search for the file on my system, but it doesn't seem to exist. Is there any other way that I can generate a wlfullclient.jar file?

Answer (score 1):

> but it appears the installation I have for weblogic doesn't include the server/lib folder

IMHO you have a corrupt or invalid installation. I dont think its possible for WL to function without the myriad jars in there.